# I don't understand how to write functions recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

So I need to call one function recursively in another function.
I have an array and first 2 parameters in function are pointers on beginning of the array and behind the end it. Third parameter is a function which I need to call recursively, and 4th parameter is a default value which I named it `a_0`;
Suppose that array has elements: `a_1, a_2, a_3, ... , a_n`.
My function Result need to calculate this:

```
f(...f(f(f(a_0,a_1),a_2),a_3),...,a_n)
```

This is task for practice, for exam, and I don't understand really principle of recursion (I understand for Factorial) but I don't understand this example.

```
 int Result(int *p, int *q,int (*f)(int, int), int a_0=0) {
      //I need to return this: f(...f(f(f(a_0,a_1),a_2),a_3),...,a_n)
 }
```

Comment: What in particular don't you understand from the given  function signature? The function pointer parameter: `int (*f)(int, int)`?

Comment: No i dont understand how to call function recursively like this:
f(...f(f(f(a_0,a_1),a_2),a_3),...,a_n)

Comment: Inside the `Result()` function body, you just call `Result()` with appropriately changed parameters. If you already did that with simple operators like `+` `-` or so, there's not much difference to use `f(a,b);`.

Comment: You can not call function that `f` points to recursively from function `Result`. Function that `f` points to must call itself recursively. Or you can call function `Result` with different set of arguments.

Comment: Yes I understand, but how to change parameters every time

Comment: Recursion is just a glorified loop. All recursion can be solved by using loops. In your case just call `f` in a loop, passing the result of the previous call as the first argument. The second argument to the function `f` is the next value from the array. So something like `previous_result = f(previous_result, *p++)`.

Comment: Yes I know that, I did that, but I am trying to make this function smaller because it is possible to do it with recursion. So why would I do it in easier way, when there is more cool way. That is why I asked question.

Comment: Recursion isn't "cool". It's non-trival, makes code harder to read, understand and maintain, and is just not as straight-forward as a loop. Don't overcomplicate things (unless it's a requirement for the assignment or exercise).

Comment: It is not required, but when I see some things like this, I always think about recursion. Can you help me then?

Comment: If we still think about it as a loop, you need to loop as long as `p < q` while increasing `p`. That will iterate over all elements of the array. First try to create a recursive function implementing this "loop", without bothering about `f` or the argument `a_0`.

Comment: But I  dont know how to do that :(
I mean can you write me a function that will sum up all elements of array using racursion. That will maybe clear things to me

Comment: As long as `p < q` you call `Result`, increasing `p` each call. Return the result of the call (or zero if you reach the stopping condition).

Comment: @pino `int sum(int *t,int i,int l) { if (i==l-1) return t[i]; return t[i]+sum(t,i+1,l); }`

Comment: Recursion is cool if the language has tail recursion optimization.  I am not aware of any C++ compiler that has tail recursion optimization.  The upshot being that in C++ it is very easy to "blow the stack" when using recursion.  It won't fail when you are using your test data set of 1000 elements, but when you go into production with tens of millions elements of real data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "left fold"; you can read about it in many places online.

In each step, `a_0` should be the value "accumulated" so far; that is, if the input array is `arr` and the initial value `a0`, its values are

```
a0
f(a0, arr[0])
f(f(a0, arr[0]), arr[1])
f(f(f(a0, arr[0]), arr[1]), arr[2])
...
```

"a_0" is not a very good name, since it's only rarely the initial value, so I will rename it "accumulator".

Starting with the base case is usually a good idea when recursing.
This is the case of an empty array, and it should return the accumulated value (we can assume it has already been computed because that's what we're going to do).

```
int Result(int *p, int *end, int (*f)(int, int), int accumulator=0) 
{
    if (p >= end)
    {
        return accumulator;
    }
    else
    {
        // To be determined
    }
}
```

For the recursive case – that is, actually computing the result – you need to use the accumulator and the current element (`*p` or `p[0]`) to produce a new value to pass on, and then recurse over the rest of the array

```
int Result(int *p, int *end, int (*f)(int, int), int accumulator=0) 
{
    if (p >= end)
    {
        return accumulator;
    }
    else
    {
        return Result(p + 1, end, f(accumulator, *p));
    }
}
```

or, shorter

```
int Result(int *p, int *end, int (*f)(int, int), int accumulator=0) 
{
    return p >= end
          ? accumulator
          : Result(p + 1, end, f(accumulator, *p));
}
```